# Integration of react / redux and unity for web game developement

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, redux, unity-webgl

is there a way to integrate unity with react in a web application? Maybe even run the unity part in a subwindow.

So basically I want to use the unity part of the graphics and animations. If something interesting happens in the game, then the state in the react / redux is changes or some action is triggered.

It would be ideal if I could use some parts of the redux state in the unity part of the game. So access redux or some parts via handlers in unity.

Thanks a lot. I hope it is clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I've made a library for archiving this, you can get it from [here](https://github.com/jeffreylanters/react-unity-webgl). I've added two way communication between your React and Unity content.

You can load your Unity content as following.

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <Unity 
      src='Public/Build/myGame.json' 
      loader='Public/Build/UnityLoader.js' />
  }
}
```

If you have any further questions you can open an issue on the GitHub page.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! I will take a look on it this Sunday and open an Issue if somethings is unclear :)